# Nodejs with express jumps after 1 function is called directly to callback

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, post, express

i have a sample function in which i want to trigger 3 sql queries in one express post request

```
function getRelatedSalespersonByCardcode(req, res) {
    var reqJson = JSON.parse(req.body.json);
    var count = Object.keys(reqJson.cardcode).length;

    var tmpResult1, tmpResult2, tmpResult3 = [];


    var q = sql.open(connstr, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            q.queryRaw("SELECT Division, Salesperson FROM SomeDB.dbo.MS2_Rel_BusinessPartnerSalesperson WHERE CardCode = " + reqJson.cardcode[i], function (e, results) {
                if (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return;
                }
                tmpResult1.push(results);
            });

            q.queryRaw("SELECT SlpCode, SlpName, Memo, Commission, GroupCode, UserSign, Active, U_wpABIS, U_sweDW," +
                " U_sweATT, U_sweDIV, U_sweEMPLOYEE, U_sweRETAILER FROM SomeDB.dbo.OSLP WHERE U_sweId = " + tmpResult1[1], function (e, results) {
                if (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return;
                }
                tmpResult2.push(results);
            });

            q.queryRaw("SELECT Code, Name, U_sweSALES FROM SomeDB.dbo.[@SWEDIV] WHERE Code = " + tmpResult3[0], function (e, results) {
                if (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return;
                }
                tmpResult3.push(results);
            });
        }
    });

    res.send(200, tmpResult2);

}
```

Anyway after 1 function is called inside my req, res function the callback is triggert.. so it jumps directly to the res.send(...) line.

i've played a bit around and it seems that this is how express works.

after a bit of googleing around i found out that i have to use the async lib.

i'd like to ask why express is working like this and if anybody maybe have a better solution than the async approach. i simply need a way to realize my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no issue of express and no issue at all. This is like node.js async programming is working. Let's examine what's happening in your code:

```
var tmpResult2;

// 1. async open sql connection
var q = sql.open(connstr, function (err) {
    // 3. query sql connection
});

// 2. render result
res.send(200, tmpResult2);
```

1. SQL connection is opened asynchronously.
2. Express render is called.
3. SQL queries are executed.

As a consequence this code piece sends data to the client before the data was fetched. So the most simple solution is to invoke `res.send` inside of the callback like this:

```
var tmpResult2;

// 1. async open sql connection
var q = sql.open(connstr, function (err) {
  // 2. render result
  res.send(200, tmpResult2);
});
```

You can use the wonderful [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module to deal with the queries (Take a look at the `async` [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) function).